# FT4232H Not Appearing

Tags: pcb, usb, integrated-circuit, ftdi, ft232

I am currently testing a custom PCB using an FT4232 chip. I have had this chip manufactured and am currently trying to get it to be recognized by my PC. I have it currently connected to a USB port supplying power and data (Bus-powered configuration). It will not however be picked up by the PC. It has no presence in USBDeview.

I have tested the voltage at all of the power input pins. the VCCIO pins are all 3.3V, VCORE pins are all 1.8V and VPHY and VPLL are all 3.3V.

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it is not appearing. Any help would be appreciated.

Datasheets:

- [FT4232H](https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/DS_FT4232H.pdf)
- [EEPROM](https://au.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/21794b-74044.pdf)
- [Crystal](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_YXC-X322512MSB4SI_C9002.pdf)
- [3.3V Regulator](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2212281509_Seaward-Elec-SE8533X2-HF_C115016.pdf)
- [5V Regulator](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2304140030_BL-Shanghai-Belling-BL8062CB3TR50_C177773.pdf)

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's with the creative layout of the USB_P trace? That's not doing you any favors... I also not you have the USB lines going to a non-standard connector - are you sure you've wired it up to your USB cable correctly and not done something like reverse the USB data lines?

Comment: Hi there. The USB trace look a little funky and I will change to trombone style in the next revision. We are using screw terminals as connector. They have worked fine for us in similar boards I've developed. Just to be sure I've tried the USB in both orientations to no avail. I am positive that they are correctly labelled however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crystal won't oscillate with 4.7 uF caps on it for sure.

In fact, all ceramics seem to be placeholders with 4.7 uF in all places, which isn't the point. Also there's electrolytics in places that maybe should be ceramics.

USB specifies max 10uF of input capacitance on VBUS. Having 10uF directly on it and something like 50uF on regulator output can exceed USB energy inrush limits and trigger overcurrent shutdown on PC or hub connector.

And you are connecting U1 output 5V together with VBUS from PC. That's not bus powered, that's just shorting two power supplies together.

If you have 12V supplied to board, it can damage your PC. If you don't have 12V supplied to your board, what happens depends on your 5V regulator. If it does not have internal reverse protection, it may damage. If it does have, devices on 12V side get powered up from PC and again this may damage the regulator or PC.

Comment: Thank you @Justme! This was exactly it. Altium must have switched my capacitors around for whatever reason right before I ordered the board. I resoldered some 27pF capacitors in place of the 4.7uF for the oscillator and it worked like a charm.